# Multiple Mark() BufferReader

Tags: java

Is it possible to set up multiple marks for buffer reader so I can read ahead multiple times?

So my code is rather long but the basic idea is after set up a mark that I will be returning to, I read ahead. My code check if this "ahead" line meets some condition, if it does, it reads ahead 4 lines or 1 line before returning back to the initial line.

```
String line = in.readLine(); //reading first line
in.mark(1000);  

while(nextLine != null){
    String nextLine = in.readLine();  
    //NEED TO SET MARK HERE TO RETURN TO
    if(!nextLineType.equals("something")){
        if(nextLine meets some condition){
           //read next four lines
        }else{
           //read next line
        }
    }else{
        in.reset()
    }
}
```

How would one get around this?

Thanks

Comment: `BufferedReader` probably isn't really meant to handle this scenario. Keep the parsed data in memory yourself, in a `List<String>` of lines perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this out of the box. You could write a decorator that does it, perhaps with a stack of marks. However, if all you care about is reading and rewinding by lines, I think that a far easier implementation is to use lists to maintain "history" and "pushback."

I think that describing it will take more lines than Teh Codez, so here's a first cut at implementation (this is *not* production-quality code; for one thing, it doesn't limit the history list, so you could easily run out of memory):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ReaderBuffer
{
    private BufferedReader reader;

    private LinkedList<String> history = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> future = new LinkedList<String>();

    public ReaderBuffer(BufferedReader reader) 
    {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public String readLine()
    throws IOException
    {
        String line = null;

        if (future.size() > 0)
            line = future.removeFirst();

        if (line == null)
            line = reader.readLine();

        if (line != null)
            history.add(line);

        return line;
    }

    public void rewind(int numLines) 
    {
        for (int ii = 0 ; ii < numLines ; ii++) 
            future.addFirst(history.removeLast());
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how it's used:

```
@Test
public void testRewind() throws Exception 
{
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("foo\nbar\nbaz\n"));
    ReaderBuffer buf = new ReaderBuffer(rdr);

    assertEquals("foo", buf.readLine());
    assertEquals("bar", buf.readLine());
    assertEquals("baz", buf.readLine());
    assertEquals(null,  buf.readLine());

    buf.rewind(2);

    assertEquals("bar", buf.readLine());
    assertEquals("baz", buf.readLine());
    assertEquals(null,  buf.readLine());
}
```